# Is it an exception of 「ある」と「いる」の使い分け?

Tags: verbs

It is a basic grammar that「いる」is used to show the existence of something alive and 「ある」is to show  the existence of inanimate object in terms of 存在表現.

However, I found some people use "工夫がいる" instead of "工夫がある". Is it an exception?

> 人に伝えるコトって**工夫がいる**んです！
>
> 細胞内の物質を積極的に移動させる**工夫がいる**。

Answer (score 10):

You are confusing 「居{い}る」 ("to exist") and 「要{い}る」 ("to be necessary").

In both of your two sentences, the verb is 「要る」, so it is just a normal usage.　「工夫がいる」, therefore, means "***(it) requires ingenuity***".

For the pronunciation of these two いる's and a few other verbs that are spelled 「いる」 if written in kana, see here:

[What is the intonation variation for 居る vs 要る?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/59295/what-is-the-intonation-variation-for-%e5%b1%85%e3%82%8b-vs-%e8%a6%81%e3%82%8b/59296#59296)